# How to populate a row values into textbox when click event using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am beginning level in angularJS. Now i am trying to populate a table records into my input fields when table row click event(). How to make this any suggestions please.

Thanks in advance.:-)

Note: I didn't using any json data for showing records into table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using events. Here is a simple demo of how you can select a clicked element from a table:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.select = function(e) {
    $scope.selected = e.toElement.innerText;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
  <table ng-click="select($event)">
    <tr>
      <td>aaa1</td>
      <td>bbb1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>AAA2</td>
      <td>BBB2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  Selected <input ng-model="selected" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use follow the workflow

```
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="item in recordsArr track by $index">
<td ng-click="doCallFunction( $index)"> {{item.id}}</td> <td> {{item.name}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

// just think of your records

post if any other info required

Comment: I believe he doesn't uses any json to populate the table (so `recordsArr` is not there)